# Eclipse during correcting indentations of HTML code sets each attributes of tag in new line - how to stop it?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse during correcting indentations (Format Active Elements [CTRL + I]) of HTML code sets each attributes of tag on new line - how to stop it?

In preferences "Split multiple attributes each on a new line" is unchecked